# jhipster generator in git bash, arrows not working

Tags: jhipster

I'm working on windows 10 and using git bash.
When running the jhipster generator, I can't move the selector ">" with the arrows.
It works fine in a standard command window. 
I was wondering if someone have the same issue and could find a workaround.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Simon Boudrias (project lead of yeoman) said in [this yeoman issue](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/360#issuecomment-295618916) :

> Git Bash is not a TTY command line tool. As such, it doesn't support any interactive features.

You'd better use [Ubuntu Bash on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/commandline/wsl/about)